# How can I prevent the keyboard from covering text in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a UITextView in a ViewController that covers the whole screen but when I run the app and am typing in it, if I type down past the keyboard then it won't scroll up. It will only scroll up if I type all the way down to the very bottom of the screen, but if I type past where the keyboard is then the TextView won't scroll and whatever I'm typing is hidden. How can I work around this?

Comment: Have you tried hiding the keyboard whenever you are not typing?

Comment: @BrunoRecillas Yes but I want it where while the user is typing they can actually see what they are typing without the keyboard in the way.

Comment: okay. Do you have the scrolling enabled in the StoryBoard for that specific textView?

Comment: Yes scrolling is enabled for the textView

Comment: have u tried lifting your textview up while typing?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the frame of the textview so that it's not underneath the keyboard.

You can use this code to react to the keyboard being displayed and to get the size of the keyboard.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                   object:nil];

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)notification
{

 CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


int height = MIN(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);
int width = MAX(keyboardSize.height,keyboardSize.width);

//Place code here to resize textview

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

These are delegate methods for for textfield.

Please ensure you included `<UITextFieldDelegate>` in .h file.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: YES];
}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [self animateTextField: textField up: NO];
}

- (void) animateTextField: (UITextField*) textField up: (BOOL) up
{
    const int movementDistance = 80; // tweak as needed
    const float movementDuration = 0.3f; // tweak as needed

    int movement = (up ? -movementDistance : movementDistance);

    [UIView beginAnimations: @"anim" context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: movementDuration];
    self.view.frame = CGRectOffset(self.view.frame, 0, movement);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) was built to created this exact problem. It requires just one line of code:

`IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true`

I'd highly recommend using it instead of developing your own solution (albeit good practice, but extremely time-consuming).